# Change button text inside segment control

Tags: ios, undeclared-identifier, uisegmentedcontrol

I have segment control and code like this in .m file

```
-(IBAction)sectionswitch:(id)sender {

    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        UIImage *dekabristov = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dekabristov.png"];
        [image setImage:dekabristov];
    }

    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        UIImage *fabrika = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fabrika.jpg"];
        [image setImage:fabrika];
    }

}
```

How i can change title of action button inside segment control? If i write `[button setTitle:@"Button!"];` Xcode says "Use undeclared identifier "button", but `-(IBAction)button:(id)sender;` in .h file

Comment: This not the declaration of UIButton. you have declared a method.  D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in that way, you have not declared a button, but only an action called 'button'.

in your .h file you should do:

```
 @interface yourViewController : UIViewController {

   UIButton *button;

 }
```

and for change title of segment control you can do:

```
 [yourSegmentControl setTitle:@"Button!" forSegmentAtIndex:0]; //0 is the first
```

if you want change a title of an UIButton:

```
[button setTitle:@"Title" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right you want to change dynamically the title of the segments. You can do this with UISegmentedControl's method

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```

You will need to have an outlet property of the segment control in your xib file. Then you just do this:

```
[self.mySegmentControl setTitle:@"New title" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: No, i want to change action button inside segment control. For example: if selectedSegmentIndex == 0, button inside will be named Button, and when selectedSegmentIndex == 1, button inside will be named Button2. I have problem, because its not default button, but action button

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "action button inside segment control". If this is some UIButton that you want to change when the segment control is used... You need an IBOutlet property of that button. Then you will be able to set its title with `[button setTitle:@"Button!"];`

Answer (score 0):

**- (IBAction)button:(id)sender;** is a Method not Identifier

so for change title Text of Action button you have to write following code

```
-(IBAction)sectionswitch:(id)sender {

    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        ...
        [sender setTitle:@"AAAAA" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
        ...
    }

    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        ...
        [sender setTitle:@"BBBBB" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to change title of segment control. there is one action button (phone number) inside each segment control. so if control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 i want change number and if control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 i want change it to another number

Comment: for change action button you have to first give Tag no to That Button & apply following code [(UIButton *)[sender viewWithTag:TagNo] setTitle:@"PhoneNo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
    segmentButton.setTitle("hello", forSegmentAt: 0)
```